Unable to clear Laravel 11.x application cache using artisan command
I'm currently working on a Laravel application, and I've encountered an issue with clearing the cache. I've attempted to use the artisan command php artisan cache:clear, but it results in an error message stating "Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions."
Are there any alternative solutions or troubleshooting steps to successfully clear the cache in a Laravel application when the artisan command fails due to permission issues?

It's giving you the Permission error when you try to clear the cache? You most likely need to tweak the permissions for the storage folder and bootstrap/cache folder.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel

It looks like "Devendra Dode" posted an answer on here featuring an article they "found" on their own blog. Please don't do this! We are very strict about spam here.

Yogendra: if you are operating multiple accounts here, that's OK as long as you're not operating a voting ring. But in general it is easier to thrive here if you just operate one account and contribute good material.

Your two current answers both promote your blog - which indicates that you might not be here for the right reasons. I recommend that in all cases you mention "my blog" to show ownership, and don't add your links into every post.

Just give a permission for storage and bootstrap folder using below command.
cd yourproject
yourproject> sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ bootstrap/

Then you run the php artisan cache:clear

I have tried the solution provided, but my error hasn't been resolved.

In your .env change CACHE_DRIVER to CACHE_STORE.
